# Unexpected/undefined results when using Maps in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, set, cosine-similarity, keyset

I'm doing some work trying to recommend documents, and to do so I am using the Cosine Similarity method. Here is the code for that method:

```
static double cosineSimilarity(HashMap<String, Double> v1, HashMap<String, Double> v2) 
{
    Set<String> both = v1.keySet();
    both.retainAll(v2.keySet());
    double sclar = 0, norm1 = 0, norm2 = 0;
    for (String k : both) 
    {
      sclar += v1.get(k) * v2.get(k);
    }
    for (String k : v1.keySet())
    {
      norm1 += v1.get(k) * v1.get(k);
    }
    for (String k : v2.keySet()) 
    {
      norm2 += v2.get(k) * v2.get(k);
    }
    return sclar / Math.sqrt(norm1 * norm2);
}
```

The problem is that the outcome varies depending on the order that the parameters are passed. For example if I call `cosineSimilarity(v1, v2)` it will return `0.3` but if I call `cosineSimilarity(v2, v1)` it will return a completely different value.

I figure this has something to do with the fact that `Map.keySet()`  returns a set backed by the map, but I do not fully understand the implications of this.

Can anyone see where the method is going wrong?

Comment: that is some awful formatting, use curly braces they are your friend.

Comment: can you define completely different value?

Comment: you said `cosineSimilarity(v1, v2) it will return 0.3 but if I call cosineSimilarity(v2, v1) it will return a completely different value.`

Comment: Any random value, not the value it should be (which would be 0.3 in this case)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
Set<String> both = new HashSet<String>(v1.keySet());
```

instead of

```
Set<String> both = v1.keySet();
```

You shouldn't modify set you got from `keySet` method because map uses it and when you remove elements from it (by `retainAll` in your case) elements also removed from map. Example:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> mp = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
mp.put(1, 1);
System.out.println(mp); // output {1=1}
mp.keySet().remove(1);
System.out.println(mp); // output {}
```

Comment: Cheers, didn't realise that `retainAll()` would effect the Map's contents but it makes a lot of sense now

Comment: Here's a technique to reduce the risk of this sort of bug. Limit direct access to the HashMap to a class that builds it. That class can return an unmodifiable version for use in code that is only supposed to use it.